# Change the appearance of Android Search Dialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to implement search functionality into an android app using the Search Dialog. After following the documentation, I got this search dialog when pressing the search button in my app.

[image: Screenshot of the emulator]

As you can see, the search dialog is too small( the app bar can be seen below it), it is not centered, and contains the app icon near the back button.

The Search Dialog showed in the guide is centered vertically in the app bar and doesn't have the app icon near the back button, which is what I want to do for my search dialog as well. But I can't seem to find any resource on how to do it. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the code that enables the Search Dialog

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val root = binding.root
        setContentView(root)
        //Setup the app bar
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_bar_menu, menu)
        return true;
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_search -> {
            onSearchRequested()
            true
        }
        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

`searchable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

</searchable>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Code related to your problem would help

Comment: @Abِ I added the code

Comment: please post the `mainactivity` xml file, that is where the fun is

Comment: @forthelulx I added it

Comment: When using native search bar it always comes with limitations, modifying it as per your requirements always becomes difficult hence it's always better to create your own custom search bar that way you'll make sure it's easily manageable and won't require massive changes even in future.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought it was doable since that was the example presented in the guide. Thx

Comment: search view by default uses R.attr.searchViewStyle, you should be able to style it from there. But it seems like you are doing something wrong there, why you set 'android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"' ? What theme you have under this attribute?

Comment: Firstly, I wanted to use Search dialog instead of search view, so I don't think that R class applies. Secondly, that theme is for the Toolbar and not the search dialog, so why is it relevant? Can I set the alignment in the toolbar theme? As for the theme I am using, I selected one of the built in themes, no custom one. Not sure why it has that name though.

Comment: were you able to customize the search dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Using the method that you want for create a search dialog, this is the most similar aspect that it can achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwTlF.png

This is the code that I implemented:

MainActivity.class code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    
    //Here you can set the parameters of the search view

    return true;
}
```

I created a menu resource file called options_menu.xml and that's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="title"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

And the searchable xml file called search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="Your hint"
    android:label="Label text">
</Searchable>
```

I created the icon of the menu in the drawable folder but you can change to other icon if you want.

Also I leave several links to all the customizations that you can add to the searchView:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView

I hope this is the right solution for you.

Comment: I think the customization logic should be moved to `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu`, otherwise `menu` is `null`, at least if you put the snippet in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I made a different search method, I used the Android Studio search view,
that's the main activity code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.mySearchButton);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You have to create an Android Resource File, select resource type "menu", and call it as you want, after that, add this item:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/mySearchButton"
    android:title="Button"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

This code worked for me, images here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNRZy.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUt4x.png

I hope it works for you aswell.

Comment: I know this is the other approach to implementing search in android. But I wanted to know it it were possible to achieve the same appearance using the approach I presented